# How to insert javascript generated content into inactive twitter bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

He

Currently I am creating a rails 4 application and the styling is done via bootstrap 3. Now I like to add tabs on one of my models show pages (datasets, see below). This works like charm for content that comes from the database even if the content is inserted into a non active tab of bootstrap. However with content generated and inserted by javascript modules there is the problem that it only works when the tab is active on page load. This is true for multiple javascript generated contents (jcloud, gmaps4rails). For example I use gmaps4rails where the builder inserts a google map with a polygon into the datasets show page. This works good if the tab is active on load. If it is inactive the map looks like in the image below. What am I doing wrong?

**The view (dataset show haml):**

```
.page-header
  = link_to datasets_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-list-alt
    Back
  = link_to edit_dataset_path(@dataset), :class => 'btn btn-primary' do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil
    Edit
  %h1 Show dataset

%dl.dl-horizontal
  - unless @dataset.instance.name.blank?
    %dt Instance name:
    %dd= @dataset.instance.name
  - unless @dataset.url.blank?
    %dt Dataset URL:
    %dd= link_to "#{@dataset.url}", @dataset.url
  - unless @dataset.title.blank?
    %dt Dataset title:
    %dd= @dataset.title
  - unless @dataset.abstract.blank?
    %dt Dataset abstract:
    %dd= @dataset.abstract
  - unless @dataset.sampling_description.blank?
    %dt Sampling description:
    %dd= @dataset.sampling_description
  - unless @dataset.geographic_description.blank?
    %dt Geographic description:
    %dd= @dataset.geographic_description
  - unless @dataset.tags.blank?
    %dt Tags:
    %dd= @dataset.tags

%br

.row-fluid
  .span8
    %ul.nav.nav-tabs
      %li
        %a{"data-target" => "#maptab", "data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#maptab"} Map
      %li.active
        %a{"data-target" => "#wordcloudtab", "data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#wordcloudtab"} Wordcloud
      %li
        %a{"data-target" => "#datatab", "data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#datatab"} Data
    .tab-content
      #maptab.tab-pane.face-in
        #printmap
      #wordcloudtab.tab-pane.active
        #printwordcloud
      #datatab.tab-pane
        %br
        - unless @dataset.columns.blank?
          .table-responsive
            %table.table.table-striped.table-hover
              %thead
                %tr
                  %th Header
                  %th Definition
                  %th
                  %th
                  %th

              %tbody
                - @dataset.columns.each do |column|
                  %tr
                    %td= column.header
                    %td= column.definition
                    %td= link_to 'Show', column, :class => "btn btn-sm btn-default"
                    %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_column_path(column), :class => "btn btn-sm btn-default"
                    %td= link_to 'Destroy', column, :data => { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :method => :delete, :class => "btn btn-sm btn-danger"
```

**The Javascript:**

```
:javascript
  jQuery(function($) {

    var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
      handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'printmap'}}, function(){
      var polygons = handler.addPolygons(#{@bounding_box.to_json},
        {
          "strokeColor": "#FF0000"
        }
      );
      handler.bounds.extendWith(polygons);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      handler.getMap().setZoom(8);
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var h = $(window).height(),
            offsetTop = 60; // Calculate the top offset

        $('#printmap').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
    }).resize();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var h = $(window).height(),
            offsetTop = 60; // Calculate the top offset

        $('#printwordcloud').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
    }).resize();


    var word_array = #{@wordcloud}

    $(function() {
      $("#printwordcloud").jQCloud(word_array);
    });
  });
```

**The map (inactive tab):**

[image]

**EDIT:**

I added a "on click" action to the tab elements and wrapped the javascript code 
to be called on click into functions.

**The TABs (with onclick)**

```
.row-fluid
  .span8
    %ul.nav.nav-tabs
      %li.active
        %a{"data-target" => "#datatab", "data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#datatab"} Data
      %li
        %a{"data-target" => "#maptab", "data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#maptab", onclick: "buildMap()"} Map
      %li
        %a{"data-target" => "#wordcloudtab", "data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#wordcloudtab", onclick: "buildWordCloud()"} Wordcloud
    .tab-content
```

**The Javascript (function wrap):**

```
function buildMap() {
    var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
      handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'printmap'}}, function(){
      var polygons = handler.addPolygons(#{@bounding_box.to_json},
        {
          "strokeColor": "#FF0000"
        }
      );
      handler.bounds.extendWith(polygons);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      handler.getMap().setZoom(8);
    });
  }
```

Comment: map creation should be done when tab is made active

Comment: Well I was thinking about something like that however I am not very good at javascript and thus could not try it. Could you give me a hint or a small example function that works that I can learn from it?

Comment: something like `$('#maptab').on('click', function(){ createMap(); })`

Comment: Brilliant doing it on click works nice. That saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: However I have now a related problem. If I click on the tab for the first time it displays nice. If I change to another tab and come back it is the same as before with the messed up map. I will add the adapted code to the original post.

Comment: try to replace `.on` with `.one`

Comment: Cool seems the right thing to do that works. The only thing I noted is that the selector "#maptab" detects not the click on the navigation bar of the tabs. It is the map pane. So I have to click on that to generate the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue with js tabs do:

```
$(map_li_selector).one('click', function(){ createMap(); })
```

Comment: I added ".mapselector" to the link to make it finally work with your javascript. Like this: `%li.mapselect` and the selector `$('.mapselect')...` Thanks!